# Creating a table with JSON

Tags: jquery, json, html-table, getjson

I was wondering if someone could cast their eyes over this code and offer feedback as to whether i'm using the correct logic, it works and it's valid however I suspect there may be a ordering issue because the addScroller function isn't re-initialising correctly:

```
    function DeliveredReport(){

var count=0;
var content='';

spinnerOn();
$('#Results tbody').empty();
$.getJSON("/central/atv/api/json_delivered_rpt.p?fromNoTime=" + $('#fromNoTime').val() + "&toNoTime=" + $('#toNoTime').val(),
function(data){

$.each(data.results, function(i,result){
content = '<tr><td>' + result.c + '</td>';
content += '<td>' + result.v + '</td>';
content += '<td>' + result.t + '</td>';
content += '<td>' + result.s + '</td>';
content += '<td>' + result.d + '</td>';
content += '<td><a class="iconSprite" id="customer_icon_btn" title="View Customer" href="javascript:ShowCustomer(' + result.cust + ')">Cust</a>' +
           '<a class="iconSprite" id="deal_icon_btn" title="View Deal" href="javascript:ShowDeal(' + result.deal + ')">Deal</a></td></tr>';
count++;

$('#Results tbody:last').append(content);
});

spinnerOff();
if (count===0) {alert('No delivered vehicles\n' + $('#fromNoTime').val() + ' - ' + $('#toNoTime').val());}
else {zebra(); AddScroller();}

});

}
```

Zebra is the typical striping effect and AddScroller is calling the tableScroll plugin.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a template framework instead.. have a look at Knockoutjs

http://knockoutjs.com/

It even supports the MVVM pattern!

Comment: Thanks for your speedy response, I've never worked with template frameworks but I did look into backbone.js this week. Without changing the way i execute the task would you say the code was ok or do you think it's not okay and i need to implement the new framework (project is supposed to go live in 5 days)....